# Bootstrap Modal buttons do not respond to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a mare with Bootstraps buttons in a modal popover.  Whatever I do I cannot get the click event to fire. Latest Bootstrap, jQuery 1.7.1.

Inside the modal I have a footer with buttons

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#" class="btn cancelBtn">Cancel</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn dontSaveBtn">Don't Save</a>
</div>
```

And my JS that is not working (click is never fired)

```
$("#navigate-away .cancelBtn").on("click", function(event){
  console.log('Click.');
  $('#navigate-away').modal('hide');
});
```

I can prove it works by using hover instead of click (hover fires ok)

```
$("#navigate-away .cancelBtn").on("hover", function(event){
  console.log('Click.');
  $('#navigate-away').modal('hide');
});
```

It seems the click event is being swallowed internally? I see all over SO people using this exact method with no problems.  What simple thing am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This did indeed to turn out to be a conflict with another library.  It was a shocker to debug, I ended up getting it relatively simply using Allan Jardine's Visual Event bookmarklet at http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event . Thanks Allan you saved my baconator.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I can't see to use Visual Event with the modal popover. It works fine on the page, but when I activate the modal popup Visual Event stops working. Also, what was your library conflict?

Comment: Ooo sorry Adam this was a long time ago. I think perhaps it was something as stupid as a duplicate ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding preventDefault to your click event, and changing to use the `delegate` style of binding:

```
$("#navigate-away").on("click", ".cancelBtn", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Click.');
  $('#navigate-away').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Alas this is never reached.... :/ it isn't executing any part of the block.  Baffled.

Comment: Are you sure that this cancel button is contained within `#navigate-away`? Maybe the selector isn't matching correctly.

Comment: Also, does the cancel button actually exist when you bind the click event, or does it get created later?  If created later, you'll have to change your call to `.on()` to more of a `.delegate` -style rather than a `.bind` style.

Comment: I can validate that the element is correctly located as using hover instead of click works as expected. The console tells me the element has rendered however I am no JS ninja, perhaps it hasn't instanced itself fully.  I will try Delegate... standby caller

Comment: To see what I mean by the delegate style, see my updated answer.

Comment: Sadly this is not the answer.  As this behavior is totally unexpected and utterly mental I am going to put it down to my environment.  It must be something else conflicting?  I will run up a test app with 1.7.1 and this revision of bootstrap and see if I get it working.  Thank you for your help though Jake, legend